# Json display all data using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My json is

```
[{"dir":"down","sym":"oo","b":"1.35553","a":"1.35556"},
{"dir":"down","sym":"pp","b":"1.64442","a":"1.64451"},
{"dir":"down","sym":"qq","b":"104.603","a":"104.609"},
{"dir":"up","sym":"rr","b":"0.88186","a":"0.88191"},
{"dir":"up","sym":"ss","b":"1.09667","a":"1.09672"}]
```

using this jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
        url: 'quotes1.php',
        dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            $('#divToRefresh').html(json[i].dir + '/' + json[i].sym+ '/' + json[i].b+ '/' + json[i].a);
        }
    }
});
}, 1000);  
});
</script>
```

But it displays 1st data only

> up/oo/1.35553/1.35556

How can I display all the data?

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery `$.each()` and `append()` method for that

```
success: function(json){
    $.each(json,function(i,val){
        $('#divToRefresh').append(val.dir + '/' + val.sym+ '/' + val.b+ '/' + val.a);
    });
}
```

`html()` will replace existing data hence it only display the last value , but `append()` will help to concatenate data.

`$.each` is better than the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.append()` instead of `.html()`. You can also use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
success: function(json){
    $.each(json,function(i,value){
        $('#divToRefresh').append(value.dir + '/' + value.sym+ '/' + value.b+ '/' + value.a);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#divToRefresh').append(json[i].dir + '/' + json[i].sym+ '/' + json[i].b+ '/' + json[i].a);
```

.html() will replace content .append() will concate the content

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code:

```
for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            $('#divToRefresh').html(json[i].dir + '/' + json[i].sym+ '/' + json[i].b+ '/' + json[i].a);
        }
```

Use the below code:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(json), function(key,val){
  $('#divToRefresh').append(val.dir + '/' + val.sym+ '/' + val.b+ '/' + val.a);
});
```

Comment: This will only ever display the last value? html will replace the content for every item in the loop

Answer (score 0):

That's strange: I would have thought that it would rather display the last...

Try this:

```
    for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
        $('#divToRefresh').append("<p>" + json[i].dir + '/' + json[i].sym+ '/' + json[i].b+ '/' + json[i].a + "</p>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
        url: 'quotes1.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
        var dd="";
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            dd += json[i].dir + '-' + json[i].sym+ '-' + json[i].bid+ '-' + json[i].ask+'</br>';
        }
        $('#divToRefresh').html(dd);
    }
});
}, 1000);  
});
</script>
```